# change the layout of the home page

Tags: layout

I am trying to change the layout of home page to `2columns-left.phtml`.

According to my understanding if I change the template file of the "root" block, in page.xml layout file, to the above template file then the layout should change. But it is not happening.

By default, as I can see, the root block has `page/3columns.phtml` template file applied in page.xml. But when I used *template hints*, I have seen that the page is rendering with `2columns-right.phtml`.

So, I searched for `page/2columns-right.phtml` in every file and replaced it with `page/2columns-left.phtml`. Still the page is rendering the layout of `page/2columns-right.phtml`.

I made the above changes in `catalogsearch.xml` and `catalog.xml` files. (*By overriding in my new theme folder*).

what I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the layout of the homepage from the backend. `Cms->Pages->homepage` and in the `Design` tab you should have a dropdown with all available layouts. Select from it `2 columns with left bar` and save.